# WebStorm 8 showing errors for a correct HTML tag

Tags: webstorm

I am new to WebStorm 8. In my current project, everything is working fine except this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

WebStorm show errors with it. When I inspect the code, it says :

```
Selector matches unknown element bower_components
```

Nevertheless, this code works. What's wrong with this tag for WebStorm ?

**Update** :
to Iena

Here is a simple example where WebStorm 8.0.2 shows errors :

```
Selector matches unknown element http (at line 4)
```

The code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Works fine</button>
</body>
```

Comment: hmmm... This error is reported when unknown HTML element is used in css (and, indeed, there are no HTML elements named bower_components). But such errors are not reported against links in HTML file. Please can you attach a file that shows up the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` yet?

Comment: seems that CSS is injected in the href value for some reason. Did you try invalidating caches, as @LazyOne suggested?

Comment: As suggested, I did [File |Invalidate caches]. The errors remained.

Comment: Please show screenshot of such error message, preferably using Default (or Darcula) colour scheme.

Comment: screenshot here:[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4JEIenIWmXNFFyYnJ5d21BSTA/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Place caret there (on error) and invoke **Alt+Enter** -- show screenshot of that popup menu that should appear. As well as screenshot of `Settings | Language Injections`. Thnx. **P.S.** Please also use `@username` otherwise we do not get notifications of responses (unless manually check this thread).

Comment: @lazyone screenshots [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4JEIenIWmXRUtmVEpqaXllbzQ/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your [latest screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4JEIenIWmXRUtmVEpqaXllbzQ/edit?usp=sharing%5d) -- for some reason you have SASS language injected into `href` attribute of the `link` tag. *Possibly* (quite likely) it was done accidentally when typing a lot and not paying enough attention (e.g. not looking at the screen at that particular moment).

Either use `Un-inject Language/Reference` from that popup menu .. or (which is better) delete that unwanted rule completely from `Settings | Language Injections` -- 4th one from the top, the one that has "global" in "Type" column.

Comment: thanks ! I don't know when I set this unknown option.

Answer (score 4):

Place your caret on that unknown element and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then choose `Un-inject Language`.